# Aplicar `ord()` en una lista en Python

Tags: python

Necesito aplicar `ord()` a una lista como la siguiente: `a=["abc","bjk","cln"]`.

```
a="abc"
[ord(x) for x in a]

[97, 98, 99]
```

Esto es como lo tengo ahora, pero necesito que lo haga para la lista.

Comment: `[ord(x) for cadena in a for x in cadena]`

Comment: casi... pero cada string debe estar separada

Comment: `[[ord(x) for x in cadena] for cadena in a] `